# how to loop through an array to hide items

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have an html form in which the user clicks on the plus sign and it shows you a list of items, if you click on a minus sign it will hide those items

as follows:

```
    <div repeat.for="categoryGrouping of categoryDepartment">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
                                <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                                    <div class="card-content" style="padding:10px">
                                        <span class="card-title white-text truncate">${categoryGrouping.name}</span>
                                        <a if.bind="categoryGrouping.hideDetails" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light" click.delegate="Activate(user, categoryGrouping)"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
                                        <a if.bind="!categoryGrouping.hideDetails" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light" click.delegate="DeActivate(user, categoryGrouping)"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div repeat.for="categoryGroupingTypes of categoryDepartmentTypes">
                            <div class="row" if.bind="!categoryGrouping.hideDetails">
<div repeat.for="user of categoryGroupingTypes.users" class="col s12 m3 l3 ">
                                    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1" click.delegate="GetCrewProfiles(user)">
                                        <div class="card-content">
                                            <span class="card-title white-text truncate">${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</span>
                                            <p>${user.emailAddress || 'mock@email.com'}<br /></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

in type script

```
async Activate(user: userListModel[], department: any) {
        this.categoryDepartment.forEach(x => {
            x.hideDetails = true;
        });
        
            this.categoryDepartmentTypes = await this.getTypes(user, department.name);
            department.hideDetails = false;
        
        
    }

    async DeActivate(user: userListModel[], department: any) {
        
        department.hideDetails = true;
    }
```

this.categoryDepartment stores my array as follows:

```
0:{hideDetails:true, name:"Hello"}
1:{hideDetails:false,name:"Test"}
```

so the above looks as the following image

[image]

so now for example if i had to click on the "Hello" plus sign while the details for "Test" is open it  would close "Test".
How can i loop through the departments to have it remain open but only when i click the minus then it should close.
I need to pass in the department name to this `await this.getTypes(user, department.name);` method, so only the item i click on should pass that name in and not all the department names.

does anyone know how i can achieve this?

i tried doing the following

```
if (this.categoryDepartment.find(x => x.name == department.name)){
            this.categoryDepartmentTypes = await this.getTypes(user, department.name);
            department.hideDetails = false;
        }
```

but it still does the same thing, it closes on the next item i click on

Comment: Try with toggle button reference:https://help.syncfusion.com/typescript/togglebutton/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You hide everything in this loop:

```
    this.categoryDepartment.forEach(x => {
        x.hideDetails = true;
    });
```

So you can remove it.

Comment: i added that because i needed only one department name to be sent to the method, when i dont do that it ends up sending all the names,which breaks everything.Thats why i wanted to know how to loop through it